# Convenience Failable Initializers assign self

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a initializer for NSURL which can throw on failure.

I would very much like it to look like [this](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17).

```
extension NSURL {
    convenience init?(string: String, throwOnNil: Bool) throws {
        if let URL = NSURL(string: string) {
            self = URL
        } else if throwOnNil {
            throw MyURLError(string: string)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

<strike>But that syntax is no longer supported: `error: cannot assign to value: 'self' is immutable`.</strike>

*That syntax only works for struct and enum.*

Here is the only thing I've come up with

```
extension NSURL {
    convenience init?(string: String, throwOnNil: Bool) throws {
        if throwOnNil && NSURL(string: string) == nil {
            throw MyURLError(string: string)
        }

        self.init(string: string)
    }
}
```

Which constructs the URL twice.

***HELP!*** There must be a better approach that I'm not finding.

---

**UPDATE**

It turns out that self assignment in an initializer works for structs and enums but not for classes. The example I was basing my ideal code from was a struct.

Comment: You cannot redefine the `self` of classes in Swift like in Objective-C. When `init` runs, the object already has been allocated. In `init` you are just supposed to initialize it, not return a different object (but nil). Further, if an `init?` fails, this immediately propagates, you can't catch the nil state. The suggestions of Price is probably the way to go if you really want that.

Comment: @hnh Swift 1.1 allowed reassignment of `self` in an initializer (see: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17). With the removal of that feature, I was hoping for a replacement.

Comment: @jeffery-themas The failable initialisers have not been removed and still work exactly like described in that article. I don't have a Swift 1.1 flying around anymore, but I'm 98% sure 1.1 didn't allow assigning `self` *in class init* either. It always did and still does in an  `enum` or `struct` (As shown in the blog entry, it doesn't show the implementation of a class `init?` - for a reason? ;-) ).

Comment: @hnh I'm very confused. The article show an extension to `Int` which defines `init?(fromString:)` which works by reassigning `self`. Maybe the link is showing you a different article?

Comment: `Int` is not a `class`, it is a `struct` - or in other words: It is a value type. `NSURL` is an (@objc) class (a reference type). P.S.: Another thing you could do is define your own `struct URL` which wraps NSURL.

Comment: @hnh Thank you for that key piece information. I missed that `Int` was a `struct`. I'll update my question.

Comment: that seems like a terrible design. Why would you support two ways of reporting an error? It would be much simple to throw error and let the user decide whether they wont to handle it or use `try?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered a factory method on `NSURL`?  It gets you most of the way there.

```
extension NSURL {
  static func initialize(string: String, throwOnNil: Bool) throws -> NSURL? {
    if let URL = NSURL(string: string) {
      return URL
    } else if throwOnNil {
      throw MyURLError(string: string)
    } else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot redefine the `self` of classes (reference types) in Swift like in Objective-C. When `init` runs, the object already has been allocated. In `init` you are just supposed to initialize the allocated object, not return a different object (but nil). Further, if an `init?` fails, this immediately propagates, you can't catch the nil state.

Looking at the
["Failable Initializers" blog post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17)
you might think you can.
But if you look closely, the post only shows initialization of *value types*.
I.e. `Int` is a `struct` and `Color` is an `enum`.

I think the rationale is that in value types `self` is the actual value, while in reference types `self` is a special thing pointing to an object which is not fully initialized.

One workaround is to use a factory method as suggest by @price-ringo.

Another workaround - which may be particularily appropriate in this case - is
to wrap `NSURL` in an own `URL` struct. Particularily appropriate, because a URL
should be a value type in Swift ... Example:

```
struct URL {
  let url : NSURL?

  init(string: String) throws {
    if let url = NSURL(string: string) {
      self.url = url
        // or extract the values and push to struct in an even more Swifty
        // way
    }
    else {
      throw URLError()
    }
  }

  // define methods which wrap url ...
}
```

Depends a little which one is more appropriate.