# How can I make that an object of the same class become the return value of initializer?

Tags: swift, convenience-methods

I have this function:

```
extension UIImage {

    static func from(layer: CALayer) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.frame.size)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let outputImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return outputImage
    }

}
```

How can I change it into like this?

```
extension UIImage {

    convenience init(layer: CALayer) {
        self.init();
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.frame.size)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let outputImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self = outputImage; // Error: cannot assign to self: self is immutable
    }

}
```

I want that the result of `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` becomes the initiated "self". But the result is already a `UIImage`. I don't suppose I should use "mutating" in this function?

Comment: What was wrong with what you had to start with? A static factory method is _exactly_ the way to do this.

Comment: I think you can't; see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37612406/433373

Comment: @matt I do not want to create a factory method. I want to create an initializer, which works slightly looks like a "type cast" sort of matter. I do not _produce_ an image. My intent is to _convert_ a type of image from one type to another, which is why the form of factory is not exactly communicating my intent.

Comment: @NicolasMiari yeah I kinda guess that, but I just curious whether if we have some workaround with this limitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states `UIImage` is immutable. What you can do is to get a `CGImage` from your outputImage and use `UIImage` `init(cgImage: CGImage)` [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624090-init) to initialize a new image from it:

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(layer: CALayer) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, 0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
        }
        layer.render(in: context)
        guard let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.cgImage else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(cgImage: outputImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh, I never thought of using the `cgImage` initializer. Thanks!

Comment: Very clever indeed! :-)